# Crop image with JavaScript works in IE but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom-events, crop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do we prevent default actions in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886306/how-do-we-prevent-default-actions-in-javascript)

In the code below I try to create a zoom feature for Charts. I tested it on IE and it worked but when I try it on Firefox, it seems that the browser doesn't cancel the default action and tries to drag the whole image. I cannot figure out why it does not work!

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3U39E/7/)

```
<img onmousedown="startDrag" onmousemove="drag" onmouseup="stopDrag" src="ChartImageSource">
MouseDownPosition = null;

startDrag = function (s, e) {
    if (!this.MouseDownPosition && e.which == 1) {
        this.MouseDownPosition = {
            x: e.clientX,
            y: e.clientY
        };
        this.Box = document.createElement("div");
        $(this.Box).attr('id', 'zoomBox').css({ 'border-style': 'solid', 'border-color': 'black', 'border-width': '1px', 'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': '1000', 'left': e.clientX + 'px', 'top': e.clientY + 'px', 'width': '0px', 'height': '0px' });
        $(s).parent().append(this.Box);
    }
};
drag = function (s, e) {
    if (this.MouseDownPosition) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var initX = this.MouseDownPosition.x;
        var initY = this.MouseDownPosition.y;
        var curX = e.clientX;
        var curY = e.clientY;
        var left;
        var top;
        var width;
        var height;
        if (curX - initX >= 0) {
            width = curX - initX + 'px';
            left = initX + 'px';
        } else {
            width = -curX + initX + 'px';
            left = curX + 'px';
        }
        if (curY - initY >= 0) {
            height = curY - initY + 'px';
            top = initY + 'px';
        } else {
            height = -curY + initY + 'px';
            top = curY + 'px';
        }
        $(this.Box).css({ 'width': width, 'height': height, 'left': left, 'top': top });
    }
};
stopDrag = function (s, e) {
    if (this.MouseDownPosition) {
        var initX = this.MouseDownPosition.x;
        var initY = this.MouseDownPosition.y;
        var curX = e.clientX;
        var curY = e.clientY;
        var curOffX = e.offsetX;
        var curOffY = e.offsetY;
        var initOffX = ((curX - initX) ? initX - curX : -(initX - curX)) + curOffX;
        var initOffY = ((curY - initY) ? initY - curY : -(initY - curY)) + curOffY;
        var MinPixX = initOffX <= curOffX ? initOffX : curOffX;
        var MaxPixX = initOffX >= curOffX ? initOffX : curOffX;
        var MinPixY = initOffY <= curOffY ? initOffY : curOffY;
        var MaxPixY = initOffY >= curOffY ? initOffY : curOffY;
        s.parentNode.removeChild(this.Box);
        this.MouseDownPosition = null;
    }
};
```

Comment: I made it work with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/tGmYS/3/

Answer (score 1):

You generally need to `return false;` from the event handlers to bypass the default action.

Alternatively, jQuery provides `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` functions. You'll probably need to call both of them, but IMO that's very verbose and the alternative (`return false;`) also works when you're not using jQuery.

[Further discussion on the alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault();` is not enough. You'll need to call `e.stopPropagation();`, too.

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: Tried e.stopPropagation() but not working. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3U39E/8/)