# Bootstrap modal popup with page without page refresh

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing an application in ASP.Net using C#. In my page i am using JQuery and bootstrap for modal popup display. I have taken some html button for display popup. But I am facing a problem to display modal popup. When I am clicking on the button modal popup is showing and page is getting refreshed. I don't know why is page getting refreshed. as per my knowledge JQuery works at client side.

Please look at the following code of buttons.

```
<a id="editPhoto" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="gen_all_es()" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:5px;" href="jcorp.aspx?paramControl=imagePhoto&responsePage=DesignCenter_Static.aspx&templateName=5">Add / Modify Photo</a>

<button id="editDesignation1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:5px;" data-target="#selectDesignation1_Modal" data-toggle="modal">Select Designation 1</button>
<button id="editDesignation2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:5px;" data-target="#selectDesignation2_Modal" data-toggle="modal">Select Designation 2</button>
<button id="editUploadLogo" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:5px;" data-target="#selectLogo_Modal" data-toggle="modal">Select & Upload Logo</button>
```

Please help.

Comment: Probably your click event handler is not preventing the default action of the link, which is loading the page in the href attribute. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886306/how-do-we-prevent-default-actions-in-javascript)

Comment: use BootBox for modals.Its very easy to integrate it.

Comment: @DanielJ.G. Facing same problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is likely due to the href on the `a` tag for editPhoto causing the url refresh

change your `gen_all_es()` function to use preventDefault on the event

html:

```
<a id="editPhoto" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="gen_all_es(event)" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:5px;" href="jcorp.aspx?paramControl=imagePhoto&responsePage=DesignCenter_Static.aspx&templateName=5">Add / Modify Photo</a>
```

javascript:

```
function gen_all_es(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kv6r28a3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this site for model popup

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/589445/JavaScript-Modal-Popup-Window
```

Also check this code for your requirement

Page JavaScript:

```
function myPop() { 
    this.square = null;
    this.overdiv = null;

    this.popOut = function(msgtxt) {
        //filter:alpha(opacity=25);-moz-opacity:.25;opacity:.25;
        this.overdiv = document.createElement("div");
        this.overdiv.className = "overdiv";

        this.square = document.createElement("div");
        this.square.className = "square";
        this.square.Code = this;
        var msg = document.createElement("div");
        msg.className = "msg";
        msg.innerHTML = msgtxt;
        this.square.appendChild(msg);
        var closebtn = document.createElement("button");
        closebtn.onclick = function() {
            this.parentNode.Code.popIn();
        }
        closebtn.innerHTML = "Close";
        this.square.appendChild(closebtn);

        document.body.appendChild(this.overdiv);
        document.body.appendChild(this.square);
    }
    this.popIn = function() {
        if (this.square != null) {
            document.body.removeChild(this.square);
            this.square = null;
        }
        if (this.overdiv != null) {
        document.body.removeChild(this.overdiv);
        this.overdiv = null;
        }

    }
}
```

Now the HTML page, using the JavaScript file:

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="NAME OF THE PAGE!.js"></script>
    <style>
        div.overdiv { filter: alpha(opacity=75);
                      -moz-opacity: .75;
                      opacity: .75;
                      background-color: #c0c0c0;
                      position: absolute;
                      top: 0px;
                      left: 0px;
                      width: 100%; height: 100%; }

        div.square { position: absolute;
                     top: 200px;
                     left: 200px;
                     background-color: Menu;
                     border: #f9f9f9;
                     height: 200px;
                     width: 300px; }
        div.square div.msg { color: #3e6bc2;
                             font-size: 15px;
                             padding: 15px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 300px;
                padding: 20px; margin: 20px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pop = new myPop();
        pop.popOut("Test");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```